# Раскрыть категорию меню с товаром на странице

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Добрый день!

Имеется меню вот такой структуры :

```css
.menu_left_catalog {
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown_radio {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown_radio a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown_radio [data-toggle="dropdown_radio"] {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.dropdown_radio [data-toggle="dropdown_radio"]:hover {
  background: #242424;
}

.dropdown_radio [data-toggle="dropdown_radio"]:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '\25BC';
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #fff;
  top: 13px;
  right: 10px;
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

.dropdown_radio>.dropdown-menu-radio {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
  animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
}

.dropdown_radio>.dropdown-menu-radio li {
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown_radio>.dropdown-menu-radio li a {
  display: block;
  color: #242424;
  background: #ebebeb;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #242424;
}

.dropdown_radio>.dropdown-menu-radio li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.dropdown_radio>input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown_radio>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.dropdown-menu-radio {
  max-height: 9999px;
  display: block;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
  animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown_radio>input[type="checkbox"]:checked+a[data-toggle="dropdown_radio"]:before {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

@keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu_left_catalog">
  <li class="dropdown_radio">
    <li class="dropdown_radio">
      <input name="menu_tog" type="checkbox">
      <a class="menu_left" data-toggle="dropdown_radio">Категория</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu-radio">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Товар</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown_radio">
      <input name="menu_tog" type="checkbox">
      <a class="menu_left" data-toggle="dropdown_radio">Категория</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu-radio">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Товар</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при переходе на страницу товара, разворачивалась (была в развернутом виде) та категория, к которой относиться данный товар

К примеру если мы открываем товар1, то в развернутом виде была бы категория 1, если товар2 принадлежит к другой категории , то соответственно категория 2 и т.д.

Можно ли это как-то реализовать?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Можно использовать location.hash, если ссылка имеет формат аналогичный этому: www.example.com/.../shop#1
Тогда показывать товар, id которого находится в location.hash

Comment: Что бы сказать подробнее нужен оригинальный js код, или его и надо написать? Я что-то не понял

Comment: вот ссылка на живой пример - http://vkusno-est.by/katalog/rastitelnyie-slivki/slivki-universalnyie-rastitelnyie-33,5.html

Answer (score 0):

```
        <ul class="menu_left_catalog">
                <li class="dropdown_radio">
                  <li class="dropdown_radio">
                    <input class="checker" name="menu_tog" type="checkbox"  >
                    <a class="menu_left" data-toggle="dropdown_radio">1 КАТЕГОРИЯ</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu-radio">
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Товар</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                <li class="dropdown_radio">
                    <input class="checker" name="menu_tog" type="checkbox" >
                    <a class="menu_left" data-toggle="dropdown_radio">2 КАТЕГОРИЯ</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu-radio">
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Товар</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown_radio">
                    <input class="checker" name="menu_tog" type="checkbox" >
                    <a class="menu_left" data-toggle="dropdown_radio">3 КАТЕГОРИЯ</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu-radio">
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Товар</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown_radio">
                    <input class="checker" name="menu_tog" type="checkbox" >
                    <a class="menu_left" data-toggle="dropdown_radio">4 КАТЕГОРИЯ</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu-radio">
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Товар</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        </ul>

              <script>
                  var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown_radio') 
                  var check = document.getElementsByClassName('checker')
                  var category = localStorage.getItem("category")

                  var showMenu = function(){
                    for (let i = 0; i<menu.length; ++i) {
                      if (category==menu[i].innerText){
                        //console.log(
                          check[i-1].setAttribute("checked","true")
                          //)
                      }

                    }

                  }()    


                  for (let i = 0; i<menu.length; ++i) {
                      menu[i].onclick=function(){
                      localStorage.setItem("category", menu[i].innerText); 

                      }
                  }


                  </script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!  Решение Ваше сначала работало не корректно, а затем категории и вовсе перестали разворачиваться (  Вот ссылка на живой пример - [ссылка]http://vkusno-est.by/katalog/rastitelnyie-slivki/slivki-universalnyie-rastitelnyie-33,5.html[ссылка]